# Get no last modified timestamp when I request google people api

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client, google-people-api

I want to upgrade my little tool from google contact api to google people api. The authorization is working and I get contacts from peopeService.
But the person.Metadata source item array has only one item type "CONTACT". I do miss the 'updateTime' in person.Metadata.Sources.
The code snipped:

```
PeopleResource.ConnectionsResource.ListRequest peopleRequest =
   peopleService.People.Connections.List("people/me");

if (pageToken != null)
{
   peopleRequest.PageToken = pageToken;
}

peopleRequest.RequestMaskIncludeField = 
   person.names,person.organizations,person.birthdays,person.biographies, 
   person.emailAddresses,person.Metadata,person.PhoneNumbers,person.Addresses,
   person.userDefined";
ListConnectionsResponse people = peopleRequest.Execute();

if (people != null && people.Connections != null && people.Connections.Count > 0)
{
   foreach (var person in people.Connections)
   {
      ConvertGooglePerson2ContactItem(person);
   }

   if (people.NextPageToken != null)
   {
      GetAllContactItems(people.NextPageToken);
   }
}
```

Get Source data:

```
if (person.Metadata!=null)
foreach (var item in person.Metadata.Sources)
{
...
}
```

Screenshot of debug session:
[image: Empty Metadata.Sources]

Maybe this is an issue with the query parameters [Link](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22names%2Corganizations%2Cbirthdays%2Cbiographies%2CemailAddresses%2Cmetadata%2CPhoneNumbers%2Caddresses%2CuserDefined%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22connections%2Fmetadata%2Fsources%2FupdateTime%22%7D#query-parameters). But I don't know how to set this query parameter.

-------- added on  Jan 6 '21  as questions of comments --------

I have tried this API: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list

With both fields set: personFields and requestMask.includeField:

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Please specify only one of requestMask or personFields.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

The result of personFields only please see questions.

The metaData with personFields only of person was given:

```
      "resourceName": "people/c623380167042605258",
      "etag": "%Eg4BAj0FBwk+Cz8MEEA3LhoEAQIFByIMcG9JRnpDRzBxS0U9",
      "metadata": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "type": "CONTACT",
            "id": "8a6b0f5889920ca",
            "etag": "#poIFzCG0qKE=",
            "updateTime": "2021-01-04T22:44:04.913Z"
          }
        ],
        "objectType": "PERSON"
      },
```

Maybe it's an API problem?

How can I get last modified time of the people contact?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem. Using the `people.connections.list` method you can retrieve the updateTime by default. It is located in the JSON response at `connections/metadata/sources/updateTime`.

Comment: You can check out [this example](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22names%2Corganizations%2Cbirthdays%2Cbiographies%2CemailAddresses%2Cmetadata%2CPhoneNumbers%2Caddresses%2CuserDefined%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22connections%2Fmetadata%2Fsources%2FupdateTime%22%7D) which uses the Try this API feature to see that the `updateTime` is returned.

Comment: Also, there are more types than just `CONTACT` for the `person.metadata.source` enum. You can see these [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.SourceType).

Comment: @Rafa Guillermo I have added a screenshot of debug session. The Metadata.Source Array contains only one item type "CONTACT".
I expect more entries here among others the update time.
Is this an issue of the RequestMaskIncludeField or other request parameters?

Comment: Where are you specifying the personFields mask for your request? Did you check out the Try This API feature to see if this is reproducible?

Comment: @Rafa Guillermo
I have not yet tried this API: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list
I've tried now. The result was not as expected.
With both fields set: personFields and requestMask.includeField: 400 Bad Request
The result of personFields only please see questions. I have added this to questsion.

Comment: Can you provide your full request to the API when you make the call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is solved with this code snippet:

```
var updateTime = person.Metadata.Sources.FirstOrDefault().UpdateTime;
```

Be sure using the Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1 Google APIs Client Library in your project.

Comment: There can be multiple sources make sure to find the most recent datetime if there is more than one source.