# google.apis.people.v1.data.Source.updateTime is Missing

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-people-api

I am trying to get Contact's last updateTime info but in dotnet api it's missing.
[Reflected Source Class code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHANI.png)

So i could not use code that mentioned in this post: [Get no last modified timestamp when I request google people api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65455181/get-no-last-modified-timestamp-when-i-request-google-people-api)

I am using service.People.Connections.List method. Also this image shows installed nuget packages.

[Installed Nuget Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X93c4.png)

What is wrong here can anybody help?
Thanks...

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code not images of your code.

Comment: @DaImTo it's not my codes at all i show reflected library codes. And libraries that i am using.

Comment: You are posting an image of an old library (Google.Apis.People.V1.Data) which does not exist anymore. Its actually the Old Google plus api.   Get the proper package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is you are using two NuGet packages and they are clashing.

You should be using [Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1/) this is the library for the Google People api.

The other one is the old library (Google.Apis.People.V1.Data) for when People API was actually google plus api and it was renamed to people api.  This caused a lot of problems. It was then renamed to people service.

I'm surprised you could even find it it I thought we unlisted from NuGet ages ago.  I just tried [searching](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=google%20apis%20people) for it and I cant find it. Could this be an old refence in your project that you have not removed?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realised now. It's also 1.25... version is installed. I did not know how and when it's installed. Because this is a developer team's project.
Thanks again.